# Checking multiple fields (string fields and date fields) in a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (`df`) that looks like:

```
Id                  Status  Date of entry to current post  Date of entry to current payband
 1  NEW ENTRANT - EXTERNAL                       1/1/2020                         1/1/2019
 2                 CURRENT                       1/1/2020                         1/1/2020
```

I am trying to write a validation that returns any records that have a `Date of entry to current post` that is before `Date of entry to current payband` and the `Status` field is a new entrant type (there are a few hence the wildcard).

I have tried the following without success

```
df['Date of entry to current post']>df['Date of entry to current payband'] & df['Status'] =='NEW ENTRANT*')
```

So in this example I would like returned:

```
Id                  Status  Date of entry to current post  Date of entry to current payband
 1  NEW ENTRANT - EXTERNAL                       1/1/2020                         1/1/2019
```

How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing to the **string** `'NEW ENTRANT*'` meaning a string actually containing the `*` character.

What you want is:

```
... & df['Status'].str.match('NEW ENTRANT'))
```

But if the date columns actually contain strings, you will compare them in lexicographic order which is probably not what you want...

Answer (score 1):

If you have datetime columns for your dates, this should work:

```
import numpy as np
df['Condition'] = np.where((df['Date of entry to current post']>df['Date of entry to current payband']) & (df['Status'] =='NEW ENTRANT*'), 1, 0)
df = df.loc[df['Condition'] == 1)
```